# Problems using subselect

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data set with multiple rows and 3 columns.  The first column `race` is filled with `0`s, `1`s, and `NA`s. I am trying to pull out the rows corresponding to the `0`s while also ignoring any `NA`s.

My code:

```
dt = data.table(cbind((data[,'race']), (data[,'age']), (data[,'sex'])))
data = dt[complete.cases(dt), ] #remove the NAs
subset(data,race == 0)
```

I keep getting this error and I am not sure what it means:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(x, r, vars, with = FALSE) : 
  i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could 
  return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). 
  Please let datatable-help know if you'd like this, or add your 
  comments to FR #1611.
```

Comment: `subset` must be applied to a data frame, not a data table, I think...

Comment: @juba, nope, it works on `data.table` as well. It is probably not the fastest way though (compared to keying and subsetting using key columns).

Comment: @LaurenMeaser, seems to work fine for me on a constructed example. You should provide us with your data if you want us to debug the problem.

Comment: @Arun Sorry for the confusion, thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: Is there a reason _not_ to use `data[race==0]` ?

Comment: @LaurenMeaser does it work to simply try `na.omit(dt)[race==0]`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be able to save a few steps (and gain a fair bit of speed) by using something like:

```
  setkey(dt, "race")
  dt[!is.na(race)][.(0)]
```

Comment: What's the difference between yours and just simply `dt[.(0)]`?

Comment: @Arun   `race` may or may not be the key.  Simply using `dt[.(0)]` will omit instances where the key is `NA` but not necessarily where `race` is `NA`

Comment: Ricardo, Maybe I misunderstand but what I meant was after setting `race` as the key. What's the use of removing NA entries in `race`.dt[.(0)] when key is `race` should produce the same output, right?

Comment: @Arun, of course.  If `race` is the key, then the two are identical

Comment: Great! Then why do you have `!is.na(race)`? :D:D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
na.omit(dt)[race==0]
```

The `na.omit` function will return the data table after excluding any rows that contain an `NA`.

Comment: na.omit will drop rows regardless of which column they appear in.  I'm not sure, but it sounds like the OP wants to drop only rows where `race` is NA

Comment: If that's the case then your solution is as concise as I can imagine.